PowerApps (Canvas app): How to bulk update with Patch function with composite primary key SQL server DB
I'm trying to update multiple records in SQL server DB from Canvas app using following Patch function overlaod. Table in SQL server has composite primary key (i.e. 2 fields combined make unique primary key), it's like polymorphic table relation.
Patch( DataSource, Collection )

e.g.
Table

ContactType
ContactID
Name

First 2 fields are composite primary key
My question is how can I define where clause in Patch to match 2 fields for update?
I want to update all records with single
Patch 

function with using
ForAll 

loop
